# Структура базы данных пользователей

Tags: mysql, sql

Доброго времени суток. Создаю свой мод для игры и делаю для него БД. Будет несколько серверов, для каждого их которых нужно будет регистрировать отдельный аккаунт. Нужен совет, как лучше сделать - создать для каждого сервера отдельную базу (server1, server2, server3) и в них таблицу users_info, или сделать одну базу (users_info) и в ней таблицы (server1, server2, server3). Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В случае создания одной БД с несколькими таблицами преимущество в том что БД нужно настроить только раз (создать пользователей, назначить доступ и т.д.). А вот держать несколько БД, каждую обслуживать(вместо одной) и прочее изрядно не удобно, однако вероятность того что все данные безвозвратно исчезнут в случае чего намного меньше.